# How do you install a floating floor on stairs?

Tags: floor, stairs, vinyl-flooring

I purchased a vinyl plank flooring to put in my basement and replace the old carpet down there. I would like to put this flooring on the stairs - but it is a floating floor. How can I keep it in place?

My ideas:

- Purchase stair nose and secure that, then float the rest.
- Use
  adhesive on the plank (not sure if this will work, or bleed, or have
  other unintended effects)

Answer (score 3):

I don't recommend doing what you're attempting to do but...

If you're covering 2x12 carpet treads, the 2x12 treads will need to be pulled off and have most of the overhang ripped off so you don't end up with a 2-1/2" or better overhang. Then reinstall the treads with liquid nails and screws or 16d nails.

From here, starting at the bottom, working towards the top, you'll need to secure stair nosing to the tread, possibly adding a return or two if you don't have boxed in treads. Now fill in between the riser and the back of the stair nosing you just installed. What you're thinking of doing is going to involve some work.

I've not done this with floating floor material, but I have done it with engineered planks as well as solid 3/4" prefinished hardwood.

Not sure of your location, but I can buy 4' oak stair treads for $25 each in Tennessee ( Lowe's ). 4' pine treads are a little cheaper, but the material is also softer. There's more work involved going this route and expense, but less safety concerns.

The reason my first sentence is, "I don't recommend this..." is because most stair nosing for laminate flooring is only 5/16" to 7/16" thick. If you drop something heavy on a stair nose or misstep, the nosing will most likely break.

Comment: Agree that new treads (or refinishing the existing ones) are probably the way to go. By the time you get all of the miscellaneous laminate pieces and assorted trim needed to safely clad stairs, you'll probably find it cheaper (and a lot quicker) to retread the stairs instead.

Comment: You have to glue down every piece else it becomes a hazard.  Just curious, why do you want your treads to be floating?